# Is it possible to connect to a MS Access DB on linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ms-access, import

With a rails application deployed on a linux server, is it possible to directly import data from an access database? On windows I can use win32ole to do this, but my linux server would not have this library. Is there a gem out there to accomplish this or perhaps another way to connect to an Microsoft Access database?

Note* I can't export the data from access first because 1) this would be slower and a less than ideal solution and 2) the MS Access database is a commercial application that does not give the ability to export the data I want.

Comment: "slower and a less than ideal solution" are not reasons why you *can't* do something, although they certainly could be reasons why you would *prefer not to* do something. Don't rule out a possible solution just because it is not "ideal".

Comment: True, only the second reason is really why I can't do it.

Comment: Is the database encrypted or otherwise "locked" in such a way that you cannot use something like [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) or [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) to connect directly to the tables and dump them?

Answer (score 0):

Consider exporting your MS Access data to CSV. Then import that CSV using a script with a standalone ActiveRecord connection to your Rails database.

Maybe write directly to Rails database.

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)
access_csv.each do |record|
  # >> conditional logic <<
  connection.execute('INSERT INTO STATEMENT')
end
```

Or convert the CSV into seed data file and `rake db:seed`

Answer (score 0):

You should create db dump file. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html
Copy it to local machine.
Use Siquel Pro for show db 
http://www.sequelpro.com/